# Can I use a mono bluetooth earpiece to play music and podcasts?

Tags: lumia, music, bluetooth, podcast

If I were to purchase a simple mono Bluetooth earpiece, would I be able to play music and podcasts through it from my Microsoft Lumia 640?

Background...

My last phone was a Samsung Galaxy S2. Wanting to listen to music and podcasts while cycling (and not having any dangling wires that could get caught) I purchased a simple el-cheapo earpiece, confirming that it would work with my phone.

I bought it home and paired it with the phone and tried playing a podcast show through it, but it came out of the phone's internal speakers instead. After a series of checks that it really was paired, I tired making a phone call through it and this worked fine.

The earpiece did indeed work with my phone, but only for phone calls. I don't want to use it for phone calls. My earpiece was useless for what I wanted to use it for.

Further researching, I found that there's two forms of Bluetooth audio. One designed for phone calls and another for music. My phone would not play podcasts through the inferior phone-grade earpiece. This was rather infuriating as I really wouldn't have minded the slightly lower quality. It was as if my phone was throwing a tantrum - "No! I'm not playing music through that thing! Get a better one!"

Years later, I upgraded to my Lumia (for unrelated reasons) and I recalled my past experiences. I had long since gave away the useless earpiece I had purchased before. Would I be wasting my money if I bought another one?

I can't use a stereo earpiece as I'm deaf in one ear.

Comment: Being deaf in one ear does not mean that you **cant** use and earpiece with two sets. You just don't get value from the other... but you do, because you can then play music.